# Kendo Angular Tabstrip wrapper

Tags: angular, user-interface, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to wrap kendo tab strip to have all the tabs in one place and whenever I wanted to change the tab component just change one place. With that in mind I started to wrap kendo tab strip but it doesn't work. I'm really confused at this point. this is my code : 
custom-tab-strip.html

```
<kendo-tabstrip>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

custom-tab-component.html:

```
<kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="title" [selected]="selected">
  <ng-template kendoTabContent>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-tabstrip-tab>
```

Where title and selected are inputs in this component.
At last I use these components as follows:

```
<app-custom-tab-strip>
    <app-custom-tab [title]="'title'" [selected]="true">
        test
    </app-custom-tab>
</app-custom-tab-strip>
```

Can anyone help me to find the problem of my code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use @Input() and @output() Emitter for the title and selected property because when parent component called child component then you have to pass 2 values for that because it will set the run time.